# Захисник чи все-таки оборонець?

Tags: синоніми, іншомовні-слова, росіянізм

Академічний тлумачний словник пояснює слово ЗАХИ́СНИ́К, захисника, чол. 1. Той, хто захищає, обороняє, охороняє кого-, що-небудь від нападу, замаху, удару, ворожих, небезпечних і т. ін. дій. 
Але "захисник" зустрічається в словнику іншомовних слів і трапляється в списках русизмів, а суто українською версією вважають "оборонець". То все таки русизм чи синонім?

Comment: Подібне: [Звідки в українській мові слово **охоронник**, і в чому його відмінність від **охоронця**?](/questions/1104/)

Comment: У яких саме словниках іншомовних слів і списках русизмів трапляється «захисник»?

Comment: Наприклад, http://www.jnsm.com.ua/ures/book/index.shtml.

Comment: @АлисаМоллс, дякую, що відповіли. Перепрошую, не помітив відразу відповідь. (Узагалі, коли Ви звертаєтеся не до того, хто є автором запитання чи відповіді, яке/яку Ви коментуєте, варто додавати напочатку коментаря його ім'я через `@` (он як я Ваше), інакше він не отримає сповіщення про Ваш коментар).

Comment: @АлисаМоллс, (1) **не зрозумів, де саме там написано, що це іншомовне слово або русизм**; (2) таку інформацію варто додати у запитання.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сайті [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8/) радять

> Для урізноманітнення мовлення й уточнення думки замініть слова
>   **захисник, захищати**, якщо мовиться про захист як потребу застосувати
>   фізичну силу або зброю, на стилістично кращий варіант: **оборонець,
>   боронити, обороняти.**

Слова "захисник" та "оборонець" є синонімами згідно із [Словником синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA):

> **ЗАХИСНИ́К** (особа, що здійснює судовий захист обвинуваченого), **ОБОРО́НЕЦЬ**, **ОБОРО́ННИК** (рідко), **РЕ́ЧНИК** (застаріле). *Захисники й судді об’їдались останнім мужицьким скарбом, ..вони замучили селян, що затялись на своєму* (М. Стельмах); *Опісля говорить оборонець Гната* (М. Коцюбинський);

Answer (score 0):

Слово "Захисник" ніяк не може бути русизмом, тому що в цього слова інша етимологія ніж у російського відповідника "Защитник"(рос.). "Защитник" - той що є "за щитом", але якщо у тебе немає хисту (за хистом -> захисник), то жоден щит не допоможе. Також слова "оборонець" і "охоронець" не є (були?) тотожними. Слово "оборонець" має той же корінь, що і слово "бороти", а слово "охоронець" той же корінь, що і слово "хоронити" (у значенні ховати). Люди, які стоять на захисті країни є оборонцями, тому що країну неможливо заховати. А в банку гроші ховають (хоронять?), тому й люди, які захищають щось від крадіжки є охоронцями. Також іноді у футболі гравців захисту можуть називати оборонцями, але ніколи охоронцями, бо закопувати (хоронити) ворота в газон проти правил. Відповідно російське слово "телохранители" і різного роду кальки від нього не можуть стосуватися живих людей і місце їм хіба що в мавзолеї.

Comment: -1: цей потік свідомості ґрунтується лише на субʼєктивних відчуттях автора і не ґрунтується на інформації зі словників. Саме тому ця відповідь містить увесь спектр недоліків — від неточностей до помилок.

Comment: З першою частиною: «Слово „захисник Б ніяк не може бути русизмом, тому що в цього слова інша етимологія ніж у російського відповідника „защитник“» — абсолютно згоден (тільки от би додати цитати з джерел, що підтверджують це). А от з другою, зокрема «люди, які стоять на захисті країни є оборонцями, тому що країну неможливо заховати» — ні, по-моєму, Ви надто буквально сприймаєте корені, слова з часом можуть змінювати значення (а корені — тим більше, наприклад, Ви знали, що всі слова за [цим посиланням](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2594) однокорінні).

Comment: Дійсно, з часом слова можуть змінювати значення, але в даному випадку цього ще не сталося. Наприклад на вас напали уночі - ви будете оборонятися чи охоронятися? Корені теж можуть змінюватися. Так слово боронити тепер має корінь "борон", Хоча древній корінь "бор" (бр) легко прослідковується. БРати - нема голосної всередині, бЕру - літера "е" появилась, вибІр, вибОри, вибИрати. Цей же корінь "бр" є в таких різних словах, як берегти і зброя. Є й більш неподібні слова з одним древнім коренем: слово, слух, сліпий :)

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо, себе я буду обороняти. А когось іншого — може, й охороняти. Особливо, як нападу ще не відбулося (а я виконую якісь превентивні дії). «Обороняти» й «охороняти», по-моєму, різняться перш за все 2 аспектами: (1) «оборона» передбачає активніші дії (як ще не напали, то це зазв. ще не оборона); (2) «охорона» може передбачати двобічний зачист (напр., охороняти можна злочинців — не лише не давати на них напасти, а й не давати їм напасти/утекти). Пишучи коментар до когось, хто не є автором запит./відп., будь ласка, вказуйте його ім'я через `@` (як я Ваше), інакше він не отримує сповіщення.